# how to make multiple line plots in ggplot2 without retyping each one

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame that consists of

| Protein | Concentration | OD450 | Replicate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.5 | 1 |
| A | 2 | 1.0 | 2 |
| A | 3 | 1.5 | 3 |
| B | 1.5 | 1.5 | 1 |
| B | 2.5 | 3.5 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 1.5 | 3 |

and so on for protein C,D,E,F....

I want to make a plot where for each protein and its replicates in one plot without having to use the filter command then copy and paste the ggplot command in R

Is there a way to do this? Like looping or something?

So like protein A rep 1, 2, 3 in one graph; protein B rep 1,2,3 in another graph.... and so on and so on
Then to make it into a grid so its easier to visualize?

Thanks!

chatgpt and just crappy filter command and lots of copy and paste. so the code is super messy

Comment: What sort of plot do you have in mind?  Or do you mean you'd like a separate data frame for each protein and corresponding replicates?

Comment: Yes separate line graph for each protein and corresponding replicates

Answer (score 0):

Bring the data in long format with `pivot_longer` and use `facet_wrap`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(OD450, Concentration)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Replicate), y = value, group = name, color = name))+
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))+
  facet_wrap(. ~ Protein)+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]